# PHP Regex patern, KODI season poster extractor

Tags: php, regex, arguments, kodi

In kodi Database, table tvshow, column C06 we have this kind of data :

```
<thumb aspect="poster">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xjm6uVktPuKXNILwjLXwVG5d5BU.jpg</thumb>
<thumb aspect="poster" type="season" season="6">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/5msClP3ba8iOHvpuZjU6NyzwEB7.jpg</thumb>
<thumb aspect="poster" type="season" season="3">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xG6kJnvmGme2ZgLZASFrI1PFUnY.jpg</thumb>
```

I would like with a regex pattern, to extract the http:// link :

```
1st case -> aspect="poster" => what is the general poster of the TV show
2nd case -> season="X" => Where X is the number of the season poster i want to get
```

I can't get answer for this problem, i found some regex but they just extract all link, it's not possible to filter as i need, like this one :

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $TVShowPosterString, $match);
```

Best regards,

S.

Comment: Your expected output is Unclear.  This looks near enough to html -- does it parse? If so, don't  regex.

Comment: I can't use DOMDocument, it's throw a error. i try also Simple XML, but same result, it's not understand as HTML or XML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though the contents is a document fragment (i.e. there isn't a single root element).  So you could wrap one round the current data and then load that(I have used `<data>` here, but it could be anything you want)...

```
$data = '<thumb aspect="poster">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xjm6uVktPuKXNILwjLXwVG5d5BU.jpg</thumb>
<thumb aspect="poster" type="season" season="6">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/5msClP3ba8iOHvpuZjU6NyzwEB7.jpg</thumb>
<thumb aspect="poster" type="season" season="3">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xG6kJnvmGme2ZgLZASFrI1PFUnY.jpg</thumb>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string("<data>{$data}</data>");
foreach ( $xml->thumb as $thumb )   {
    echo (string)$thumb.PHP_EOL;
}
```

gives the links...

```
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xjm6uVktPuKXNILwjLXwVG5d5BU.jpg
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/5msClP3ba8iOHvpuZjU6NyzwEB7.jpg
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xG6kJnvmGme2ZgLZASFrI1PFUnY.jpg
```

Comment: I copy the full data row to paste bin : https://pastebin.com/ScxG1cNN when i use this, simple XML throw many error, like some special char cut all the string.

Comment: It didn't seem to have problems with the copied data.  You could try `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` before the `simplexml_load_string` and see if that suppresses the errors.

Comment: i get it working with stripslashes() thks